# Looking for better approach to deal with lots of parameters

Tags: c#

I have implemented a form of Steering behavior for a game, and per use of an editor, a designer should be able to choose for (currently) seven parameters whether or not they should be 0, random or a set amount, and in case of the latter two, in which range random should fall or which set amount the variable should get. The settings will be saved in a file, and have to be able to be loaded in at any time.

What I ended up with is a painful to look at constructor and a whole, whole lot of fields and properties. 
*I am looking for a more intelligent approach to solve this problem, especially when adding more parameters later.*

```
public enum SteerType
{
    None,
    Random,
    Variable
}

public IdleSteering(SteerType rotationOnIntervalType, int rotationOnInterval, 
                    SteerType rotationOnCollisionType, int rotationOnCollision,
                    SteerType breakIntervalType, int breakInterval,  
                    SteerType breakTimeType, int breakTime, 
                    SteerType rotationOnBreakType, int rotationOnBreak, 
                    SteerType rangeFromSpawnType, int rangeFromSpawn, 
                    SteerType speedType, int speed)
    {
        _rotationOnIntervalType = rotationOnIntervalType;
        _rotationOnInterval = rotationOnInterval;

        _rotationOnCollisionType = rotationOnCollisionType;
        _rotationOnCollision = rotationOnCollision;

        <...> //And this five more times
    }
```

And the following chunk for every single parameter, so seven times as well.

```
private SteerType _rotationOnIntervalType;
    private float _randomRotationOnInterval;
    private float _rotationOnInterval;
    public float RotationOnInterval
    {
        get
        {
            switch (_rotationOnIntervalType)
            {
                case SteerType.None:
                    return 0;
                case SteerType.Random:
                    if (_randomRotationOnInterval.Equals(0))
                        _randomRotationOnInterval =
                            MathHelper.ToRadians((float)(-Static.Random.NextDouble() + Static.Random.NextDouble()) * _rotationOnInterval);
                    return _randomRotationOnInterval;
                case SteerType.Variable:
                    return _rotationOnInterval;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest creating a class to hold the 2/paired values, and then group into a collection:

```
public class Steering
{
    public SteerType SteerType{get;set}
    public int Amount{get;set}
}

List<Steering> userSteering = new List<Steering>
  {
     //initialize your list
  };

//pass that list into a constructor.
```

Over in your IdleSteering class:

```
private List<Steering> steeringValues;

public IdleSteering(List<Steering> userSteering)
{
    steeringValues = userSteering;
}

//we can now use LINQ to find any particular steering value.
int braking = steeringValues.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.SteerType==Random).Amount;
```

Pass and use that collection between all your methods.

Comment: Instead of a list it's also possible to use `public IdleSteering(params Steering[] userSteering)`

Comment: I think this solution will definitely work in my case, thank you.

Comment: @Darcara you betcha! I was just using any old collection to illustrate how to implement. YMMV on the datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

Use a settings object - refactor these parameters into a class and pass that class in. You can add additional parameters without an issue.

This is called a [parmeter object refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) and has been used in several places in the BCL - the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class being one.

An added bonus to this approach is that you can serialize and deserialize the settings separately from the class using them.

Comment: That would definitely work for the constructor itself, but still means I'd have to copypaste and edit the second chunk of code for every new parameter I'd add. So this only partially answers my question.

Comment: @Taelia - There are several ways to solve this issue. A holding class for each pair would help. Passing in a list of these can be one option. If you have _separate_ behaviour as well you should consider an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious solution would be to look for patterns in your parameters. What I see is that you have combinations of `SteerType` along with an `int` that represents a speed. You then have this combination several times, once each for several different states.

Given that, you could combine these two things into a single class:

```
public class SteerSettings
{
    public SteerType Type { get; private set; }
    public int Interval { get; private set; }

    public SteerSettings(SteerType type, int interval)
    {
        Type = type;
        Interval = interval;
    }
}
```

Then change your constructor to look like this:

```
public IdleSteering(SteerSettings rotationOn, SteerSettings collision, 
                    SteerSettings break,  SteerSettings breakTime, 
                    SteerSettings rotationOnBreak, SteerSettings rangeFromSpawn, 
                    SteerSettings speed)
    {
        ...
    }
```

A more aggressive approach would be to take that and create a new enum that represents your various states and use that in a `Dictionary` to specify the various settings for each state.

```
public enum SteerState
{
    RotationOn,
    Collision,
    Break,
    BreakTime,
    RotationOnBreak,
    RangeFromSpawn,
    Speed
}

public IdleSteering(IDictionary<SteerState, SteerSettings> settings)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a collection, of potentially indefinite length, consisting of different parameters.

Why not make it with a dictionary, like so:

```
public IdleSteering(IDictionary<SteerType,int> steerSettings)
```

and then go through the dictionary keys to set and get a values.

?!?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make another Rotation with SteerType and RotationValue (and your getter, virtual if needed), and will default parameters in constructor like this (.NET 4.0 req'ed):

```
public IdleSteering(Rotation interval=null, Rotation collission=null)
    {

        _rotationOnIntervalType = rotationOnIntervalType??new Rotation(...);
        _rotationOnInterval = rotationOnInterval??new Rotation(...);
        ...
    }
```

then you would just call:

```
var idleSteering = new IdleSteering();
```

of course if properties can be defaulted...